# Flask redirect after OAuth linking to http instead of https

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine

I use the following route to redirect an authenticated OAuth user to their account page:

```
@app.route('/google/callback')
def authorized():
    resp = google.authorized_response()
    if resp is None:
        return 'Access denied: reason={0} error={1}'.format(
            request.args['error_reason'],
            request.args['error_description']
        )
    session['google_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '')
    return redirect(url_for('account',_external=True, _scheme='https'))
```

However the redirect URL is to http://[domain].herokuapp.com/google/callback. Navigating between pages within my application keeps me in an https environment; it's just when I leave the application to authenticate and get redirected back that it switches to http. Why is that, and how can I make it redirect back to https?